# Calculate $P(X+Y<3)$

Tags: probability

Given $X,Y$ two random variables, I have the joint probability $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.
The problem is compute $P(X+Y<3)$.

My original idea was define $U:=X+Y$ and $V:=Y$ and compute the joint probability $f_{U,V}(u,v)$ and later compute the marginal mass function $f_U(u)$ of $U$ and finally:
$$P(X+Y<3)=P(U<3)=\int_{-\infty}^{3}f_U(u)du$$

But i read that i can use directly the function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and compute
$$P(X+Y<3)=\int\int_{R}f_{X,Y}$$
where $R:=\{(x,y):x+y<3\}$.

Why can I use $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ of this way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int_{u<3} f_{\small X+Y}(u)~\mathrm d u &= \iint_{u<3} f_{\small X+Y,Y}(u,y)~\mathrm d u~\mathrm d y&&\text{Law of Total Probability}\\[1ex]&=\iint_{u<3} f_{\small X,Y}(u{-}y,y)~\mathrm d u~\mathrm d y&&\text{Jaccobian Transformation}\\[1ex]&=\iint_{x+y<3} f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y&&\text{Change of Variables: }x\gets u-y
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Probabilities can be looked at as special cases of expectations. In fact the expectations of random variables that only take values in $\{0,1\}$.

In this context: $$P(X+Y<3)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_R((X,Y))=\int\int1_R(x,y)f_X(x,y)dxdy$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the distribution function of $Z=X+Y$ is the following

$$F_Z(z)=\mathbb{P}[Z \leq z]=\int\int_{X+Y \leq z}f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy$$

What you are asked to do is to calculate $CDF_{Z}$ in a fixed $z=3$

Comment: In the context of your answer the posed question can be rephrased as: why is the second equality valid? Actually you only *restate* that equality. So IMV this is not an answer.